# How to prevent that closing a JDialog closes the entire application

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a main(screen) gui window and need to open a few "multi input" windows (jdialog or when not possible jframe), for example to add preferences (4 textfields with 2 filechoosers and 2 radiobuttons).
When pressing OK/Cancel in these JDialogs (or JFrames), my entire application closes.
I don't want that. How can I prevent that?

**First try**: I tried the intelliJ option "New -> Create Dialog class", which gives me a JDialog with OK/Cancel button. Pressing one of the buttons closes the JDialog and my entire application.

**Second try**: I wrote a class "by hand" which creates a JDialog (and also tried JFrame). Again: Pressing one of the buttons closes the JDialog and my entire application.

I removed "dispose()" and "setVisible(false)" options from theJDialog (JFrame), but still my entire application is closed.

**main class method**

```
public class mainScreen {

    // Menu action listener (only relevant options)
    class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

    // menuListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            //myVariables myVars = new myVariables();
        String[] dummy = null;
            System.out.println("Selected: " + ev.getActionCommand());

            switch(ev.getActionCommand()) {
                case "Preferences":
                    showPreferencesDialog();
                case "Exit":
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
    }

    // method that opens the external class (see below in following code block)
    private void showPreferencesDialog() {

        prefJDialog myprefs = new prefJDialog(prefsPanel);
        myprefs.showDialog();
        boolean okPressed = myprefs.isOkPressed();
        if (okPressed) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainScreen.this.rootPanel,"OK pressed","About jExifToolGUI",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainScreen.this.rootPanel,"Cancel pressed","About jExifToolGUI",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    // This is the class which is mention in the manifest
    public mainScreen(JFrame frame) {
        boolean preferences = false;
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot();

        createmyMenuBar(frame);
        groupRadiobuttonsandListen();
        fileNamesTableListener();
        try {
            myUtils.DisplayLogo(mainScreen.this.iconLabel);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading Logo");
        }

        preferences = check_preferences();
        if (!preferences) {
            myUtils.checkExifTool(mainScreen.this.rootPanel);
        }

        programButtonListeners();
    }
    // main method in my main class for my project
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("jExifToolGUI");
        frame.setContentPane(new mainScreen(frame).rootPanel);
        //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

**The JDialog class/method** that is called from the main class

```
package org.hvdw.jexiftoolgui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class prefJDialog extends JDialog {
    private JButton okButton;
    private JButton cancelButton;

    private JPanel prefsPanel;

    private boolean okPressed;

    public prefJDialog(JPanel prefsPanel) {
        super(JOptionPane.getFrameForComponent(prefsPanel), true);
        this.prefsPanel = prefsPanel;
        setTitle("Preferences");
        initDialog();
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        setSize(800, 768);
        double x = getParent().getBounds().getCenterX();
        double y = getParent().getBounds().getCenterY();
        setLocation((int) x - getWidth() / 2, (int) y - getHeight() / 2);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    private void initDialog() {
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 5, 10));
        add(pane);

        pane.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        FlowLayout l = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        JPanel buttonsPane = new JPanel(l);
        okButton = new JButton("Save"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        buttonsPane.add(okButton);
        pane.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        cancelButton = new JButton("CANCEL"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        buttonsPane.add(cancelButton);

        buttonsPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, (int) l.preferredLayoutSize(buttonsPane).getHeight()));
        pane.add(buttonsPane);

        addListeners();
    }

    private void addListeners() {
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //saveProperties();
                setVisible(false);
                okPressed = true;
                //close();


                // dispose();
            }

        });
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                //dispose();
                //close();
                okPressed = false;
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean isOkPressed() {
        return okPressed;
    }

    /*public void close() {
        WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);
    }*/
}
```

So how do I prevent that upon clicking OK or Cancel in the JDialog, the entire application closes. That needs to stay open until the user clicks the "window close" X in the top-right, or from the menu "File -> Exit"

I have searched Google for several days, but can't find a solution (and one same question without answer).

**Edit:**
After Patrick's answer I changed the close method to

```
    public void close() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

And removed the /* and */.
I also activated the close(); in the listeners again, but it doesn't make a difference. My main app is still closed.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I added minimal code from my main class and the complete class of my called JDialog class.

Comment: *I wrote a class "by hand"* - that is the correct approach so you learn how to use Swing an not the IDE. *I added minimal code* - minimal code means you create a JFrame with a "Show Dialog" JButton. When you click the button you display a JDialog with a "Close" button. All the code will be in one class that we can copy/paste/compile/test. We can't do that with your code since there is no JFrmae, there is no main() method etc. Also all the code related to centering the frame/dialog is irrelevant to the question. Only code directly related to the problem is needed.

Comment: Understood.  But my main (manifest) class is now 530 lines with 6 additional classes for all functionality. See also a shared image of the main screen (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k7NKK4ynTyc5-w9h_Bj8UuSfVpTtxIa_/view?usp=sharing). The next steps were a few Jdialogs. (Note that for the time being I put the mentioned Preferences as most right tab in tabbed pane). It is actually a rewrite of my pyExifToolGUI (https://hvdwolf.github.io/pyExifToolGUI/) as I already program Android java.

Comment: We are not her to debug your application. We are here to help you understand basic Swing concepts. A JDialog is specifically designed to NOT close the entire application. Prove this to yourself by creating a simple example as I described in my previous comment. Unless you have code like `System.exit()`, closing a dialog will not close the application! If you can't duplicate the described problem with a proper [mcve] then we can't help.

Comment: Please don't edit the question title with noise as in other forums like [Solved], the way we do it in StackOverflow is by accepting an answer (which you already did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     switch(ev.getActionCommand()) {
            case "Preferences":
                showPreferencesDialog();
            case "Exit":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
```

And the problem is that you don't have a `break` statement in your switch case so the code falls through to the "Exit" logic and does a `System.exit(0)`

This is why we need a proper "MCVE" with every question. When you post random pieces of code we can't see the entire logic flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for spotting this. There are 8 (at this moment) case statements and this is the only one missing the "break;" comand and it happens to be right before the exit.  I will try to better my life. Sorry, I can't upvote your answer as I do not have enough posts.